# How to access a string returned from the server

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I have inherited a legacy web app, that uses spring. I can see that the HTML code calls the java class, and the java class returns a ModelAndView object. That is perfectly fine, but what I do not understand at the moment, is how to get access to a specific String value, in the HTML code? What I am looking for is the specific syntax - I have tried the following:

```js
$.get("https://mymachine:444/myapp/TestAction.action", {param:selectedParam})
 .done(function( pbURL ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + {pbURL} );
    });


// and the java...
String pbURL = "https://blablahblah";
request.setAttribute("pbURL", pbURL);

return new ModelAndView("player");
```

The corresponding piece of code in java would populate a variable called pbURL, and this is what I am trying to extract but obviously failing....

Comment: if it's a model and view object and the function return "foo" then it's probably a named view, if you're spring project contains jps files search for "foo.jsp". Otherwise check spring configuration, check for classes `*viewResolver` like  `InternalResourceViewResolver` or `XmlViewResolver`

Comment: I need more information please -  if I set the attribute property like above, how can I retrieve that particular field in the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ResponseEntity instead of modelandview to return string to client like this

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/returnString",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> returnString() {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("player", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: I am still struggling with this issue. We are using Spring version 4.I am using ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
     mav.setViewName("newplayer");
     mav.addObject("playbackURL", "http://www.helloharriet.com/"); Then in the HTML code, I call a jQuery that looks like this:                     $.get("https://mymachine:444/myapp/TestAction.action", {callID:selectedCallID})

                    .done(function( playbackURL ) {
                        alert( "Data Loaded: ${playbackURL}");
                    });

                 });
            });

Answer (score 1):

So request.setAttribute won't ever work, the request object is an abstraction of what the client's requests. Manipulating it won't change the `response`.

Your response is the following piece of code :

```
return new ModelAndView("player");
```

If you want to change that you have two way :

- Not returning anymore a ModelAndView, instead using directl the response object and write it in.
- Find where the `player` view is defined (player.jsp maybe ?) and pass your parameter in the HTML/JSON/ ??? generated by spring. For this you will need the following piece of code :

  ModelAndView mav = ModelAndView("player");
   mav.setAttribute("pbUrl", pbUrl);
   return mav;

Then supposing your player refer to a jsp :

```
<input type="hidden" id="pbUrl" value="${pbUrl}"/>
```

If this HTML is then inserted somewhat in the full page you can the use a `document.getElementById('pbUrl').value`